# Define a property with get/set behaving like a normal property

Tags: javascript, properties

Consider the following code:

```
function Foo(){this.bar=42;}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, "baz", {
  get:function(){return 25;},
  set:function(val){}
});
var foo = new Foo();
for(var x in foo) console.log(x);
```

I can (if the rest is implemented too) use `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` w/o noticing that the latter is not a "real" property.

But it does not appear in the for loop which breaks my code.

I basically want to intercept when the property is set and e.g. react to it or delegate to something else.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to your defined property not being `enumerable`. From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> `enumerable`
>
> `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

You can fix this by specifying `enumerable: true` in your property `descriptor`:

```
function Foo(){this.bar=42;}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, "baz", {
  get:function(){return 25;},
  set:function(val){},
  enumerable: true
});
var foo = new Foo();
for(var x in foo) console.log(x);
```

EDIT: in response to your comment regarding enumerability of properties defined by getter in objects, it seems that, yes, getters defined in object literals are enumerable but not those defined in class definitions. I'm not entirely sure where this is described in the docs but I would be happy to update my answer with this should anybody find it.

```
const foo = {
    get bar () {
        return 'baz';
    }
}

console.log(Object.keys(foo));
// ["bar"]

class Bar {
    get baz () {
        return 'qux';
    }
}

console.log(Object.keys(new Bar()));
// []
```

Comment: Great! Is this also possible for in-object property like `{get baz(){return 42;}, set baz(val){} }` I'm asking because the current code I'm working on uses that.

Comment: @Flamefire, it seems that `getters` defined in an object literal are enumerable, but not those on a class. I'm not certain where this is defined in documentation but I've edited my answer to show my naive experimentation.

Comment: Perfect. Seems I was mistaken there as they use some extension function which calls `__defineGetter__` and friends. Those can then be easily replaced by the `defineProperty` equivalent solving all issues.